# Formal identity for sum of polynomials over a finite field.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

Suppose $F$ is a finite field of order $q$ a prime power. If $f\in F[x]$ of degree $t$, set $|f|=q^t$. Let $\sigma(f)=\sum_{g\mid f}|g|$ where the sum is over the monic divisors of $f$.

> Why does
>   $$
> \sum_f \sigma(f)|f|^{-s}=(1-q^{1-s})^{-1}(1-q^{2-s})^{-1}
> $$
>   where the sum on the left is over all monic polynomials?

I have been able to verify that $\sum_f |f|^{-s}=(1-q^{1-s})^{-1}$ and that $\sum_f d(f)|f|^{-s}=(1-q^{1-s})^{-2}$ where $d(f)$ is the number of monic divisors of $f$. I can include proofs if needed. I started by writing
$$
\sum_f \sigma(f)|f|^{-s}=\sum_f\left(\sum_{g\mid f}|g|\right)|f|^{-s}
$$
and I know $\sum_{g\mid f}|g|$ consists of $d(f)$ terms, but I don't see a clever manipulation to tie it together. This sum is found in Ireland & Rosen. Thanks.

Comment: Have you used LHS is multiplicative?

Comment: @Sanchez Sorry, what do you mean? I realize that $|h|^{-s}\cdot |g|^{-s}=|hg|^{-s}$, but I don't know if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: I meant to say that $\sigma(fg) = \sigma(f)\sigma(g)$ if $f$,$g$ are relatively prime. This, together with $F[x]$ is UFD, gives that LHS = $\prod_f \sum_{n=o}^{\infty} \sigma (f^n) |f|^{-ns}$. Simplifying this would probably give you what you want, but the answer below is definitely simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_f \sigma(f)|f|^{-s}&=&\sum_f \sum_{g: \  g|f} |g| |f|^{-s}\\
&=& \sum_g \sum_{f:\  g|f} |g| |f|^{-s}\\
&=&\sum_{g}\sum_h |g| |gh|^{-s} \ \ ({\rm setting}\ f=gh)\\
&=& (\sum_h |h|^{-s}) (\sum_g |g|^{1-s}) \\
&=& (\sum_{n\ge 0} q^{n(1-s)})(\sum_{m\ge 0} q^{m(2-s)})\\
&=& (1-q^{1-s})^{-1} (1-q^{2-s})^{-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks, this is very clear.